# Vmware access to vm throug ssh

Tags: ssh, vmware, virtual-machine

i have got a vmware server 2 on centos 5.6 host. I can access my virtual machines
from host machine, but i can not access from other machines.

I have configured nat port forwarding. But somehow i have no access to vm using ssh.
I have checked all firewall settings and seems right.

What can cause this problem?

best regards,
bilal

Comment: what kind of access doesn't work? Shell or tunnel?

Comment: shell access. i am using putty for ssh connections

Answer (score 0):

It is usually easier to configure a bridge between the virtual interfaces and your host-interface. That way all your VMs will appear as real hosts on your network. Make sure you don't have "host-only" networking enabled.

For reference: [Vmware: bridged network](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html)